# jquery mobile Datebox Flipbox doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am having trouble getting flipbox to work. It displays, but I can't get the day/month/year to roll or move at all. It's frozen.

Same if I change the mode to timeflipbox, or durationflipbox -- they display when I click them but don't respond to any mouse or keyboard activity.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> 
    <title>Single page template</title> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css'>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js'></script>
<script src='jqm-datebox.core.min.js'></script>
<script src='jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js'></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role='page'>
    <div data-role='content'>


            <input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"flipbox"}'>

    </div>

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this code for the flipbox to be frozen? The only thing I can think of is that the js references are off, but I just downloaded them and I'm pretty sure they are current.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out... I just copied/pasted the css/js references from JT Sage's Datebox page source: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/